# Which one is correct/idiomatic?

Tags: idioms, expression-choice, sentence-patterns

Which one of the following is the best choice?

> The fact that only now I can see clearly was that …
>
> The fact that I can only now see clearly was that …
>
> The fact that I can see clearly only now was that …

Comment: _The fact that only now can I see clearly_ would be another variant.

Answer (score 1):

All arrangements are idiomatic and result in the same meaning. Which you use is a matter of personal preference in this particular case.

> (**CoGEL § 8.14**) There is a sharp difference between A [the adverbial element] and other elements in the relative freedom with which A [an adverbial element]  can be put in different positions in a sentence. The following examples illustrate this freedom, and we add the positional notation …
>
> - **By then** the book must have been placed on the shelf. I  [initial]
> - The book **by then** must have been placed on the shelf. iM [initial Medial]
> - The book must **by then** have been placed on the shelf. M [Medial]
> - The book must have **by then** been placed on the shelf. mM [medial Medial]
> - The book must have been **by then** placed on the shelf. eM [end Medial]
> - The book must have been placed **by then** on the shelf. iE [initial End]
> - The book must have been placed on the shelf **by then**. E [End]
>
> Some of these positions are less likely than others for the A in this sentence,
> but none is unacceptable. Of course, the availability of different positions
> does not imply that the choice of position makes no difference to the meaning
> of the sentence. The selection ofone position rather than another is influenced by several factors, but chief among them is the information structure of the
> sentence, and the relation of adverbials to information structure will require
> special attention both in this chapter and in Chapter 18. But not all A-
> elements have the same range of possible positions. The type of realization
> (cf 8.13) has a strong influence on where an adverbial is placed (in general,
> single-word adverb phrases are most mobile and finite clauses least), and of
> even greater influence are the semantic typology outlined in 8.2ff and the
> grammatical typology on which we shall concentrate in this chapter (8.24ff).